# ArchUnit classes should depend only on particular classes from a package

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

I have two separate packages:

```
mycomp.sales
- Order
- OrderPlaced
mycom.delivery
- Delivery
- OrderPlacedListener (depends on mycomp.sales.OrderPlaced)
```

I want to set a rule which checks that the package `mycom.delivery` has only a dependency on `OrderPlaced` and no other classes in the package `mycomp.sales`.

So far I came up with this:

```
JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("mycomp.delivery");
ArchRule rule = classes()
        .should().onlyDependOnClassesThat().resideOutsideOfPackages("mycomp.sales..")
        .orShould().onlyDependOnClassesThat().areAssignableTo(OrderPlaced.class);
rule.check(importedClasses);
```

But this fails on the `OrderPlacedListener` (which has a dependency to `mycomp.sales.OrderPlaced`).

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code both OR clauses are evaluated separately, it means either 1. all dependencies must be outside `mycomp.sales..` (which is not) or 2. all dependencies must be assignable to `OrderPlaced` (which is obviously not).

You have to define a compound rule like that:

```
ArchRule rule = classes()
    .should().onlyDependOnClassesThat(
        resideOutsideOfPackages("mycomp.sales..")
            .or(type(OrderPlaced.class)));
```